# Import Error when using Anaconda with Python launcher

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-import

I installed Anaconda (Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64, python 3.8). Following the installation guide, I didn't add Anaconda to the PATH environment variable. After installation, it works well when using Anaconda Prompt to start python.

Problem occurs when I use Python Launcher to start python from CMD:

In CMD, type "py" to launch python(The Python Launcher is able to find Anaconda python). Then when I attempt to import `numpy`, I get the following error:

```
Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

And when I attempt to import `sqlite3`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

If I use Anaconda Prompt to start python, I can suscessfully import `numpy` and `sqlite3`. I checked `sys.path` under these two situations and they are exactly the same.

Why? What's the difference between the two situations?

p.s.

I'm concerned with this problem because I built a website using "django + mod_wsgi + Apache", and when visiting the website from brwoser, the website got an "Internal Server Error". The error log shows that it is caused by the failure of importing numpy and sqlite3, just like the above errors.

Comment: Is that the entire error output?

Comment: No, I just put the last line of the the whole output. I realized it's a problem caused by `path` environment variable because I didn't add Anaconda path to `path` variable so the python interpreter could not find some dll file. But when I used the old Anaconda (Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64, python 3.6), I didn't encountered this problem, though the Anaconda path was not added to `path` variable either. I reinstalled the latest Anaconda yesterday, then the problem occured.

Comment: _But when I used the old Anaconda (Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64, python 3.6), I didn't encountered this problem, though the Anaconda path was not added to path variable either._ Doesn't that indicate that it **isn't** _a problem caused by path environment variable_ ?

Comment: I run `set path=C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\bin;C:\Anaconda3\condabin;%path%` in ordinary CMD, then run `py` to launch python. Then I can import numpy and sqlite3. I think it is the path problem. It's strange the old version of Anaconda didn't have this problem. I have no idea why the old Andconda can find those dll files.

Comment: That might lead to some issues. You should consider removing all trace of Anaconda/Conda, and installing it again from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between the two situations?

The anaconda command prompt has added a bunch of paths to the PATH environment variable, e.g. for me it has added all of these locations:

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\condabin
```

In some of these locations there are executables like `python.exe` so that calling `python` will launch the anaconda installed version. Other folders in this list contain .dll files, i.e. libraries that your modules might depend on (like numpy or sqlite that are interfaces to functions written in c/c++). So even if you are calling the right python.exe, if the PATH is not set to include the locations of the neccessary dlls, then importing such packages will fail, as you can see in your error messages:

```
Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What you can do:

I am not an expert on configuring a django server, but by manually adding these locations to your PATH, you might be able to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. I finally realized it's a problem of `path` variable. The strange thing is, when I used the old version of Anaconda (Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64, python 3.6), I didn't add those path to `path` variable either (following the recommendation of installing instruction). It worked very well, not only for my Apache+Django project, but  also for running `C:\Anaconda3\python.exe xx.py` in ordinary CMD window. Yesterday I reinstalled the latest Anaconda, the problem occured.